# Delete multiple files - Receive only one authentication prompt

Tags: file, applescript, directory, delete-file

I'm trying to create a script to delete multiple files in the same folder without having to authenticate twice. I've tried a bunch of things but I'm super new to AppleScript and I keep striking out. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
set colorProfiles to (POSIX file "/Library/ColorSync/Profiles")
set coatedToDelete to "Pantone+ Solid Coated.csv"
set uncoatedToDelete to "Pantone+ Solid Uncoated.csv"

try
    --Notification window with info
    display dialog ("This script will automagically delete your outdated Pantone color books. Please make sure an admin is nearby to authenticate (twice) if prompted.") with icon note

    --Deletes both Pantone+ .csv files
    tell application "Finder"
        delete file (coatedToDelete of folder colorProfiles)
        delete file (uncoatedToDelete of folder colorProfiles)

    end tell
    --Successful deletion notification
    display dialog ("The outdated color book deletion was successful!") buttons {"Great!"} with icon note


on error
    --Error message notification
    display dialog ("This script was unable to delete your legacy Pantone color books.") buttons {"OK"} with icon caution
end try
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the shell command `rm`, it can delete multiple files in one line with one authentication. The difference to the Finder is that the files are deleted immediately instead of being moved to the trash folder.

```
set colorProfiles to "/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/"
set coatedToDelete to colorProfiles & "Pantone+ Solid Coated.csv"
set uncoatedToDelete to colorProfiles & "Pantone+ Solid Uncoated.csv"

try
  --Notification window with info
  display dialog ("This script will automagically delete your outdated Pantone color books. Please make sure an admin is nearby to authenticate (twice) if prompted.") with icon note

  --Deletes both Pantone+ .csv files
  do shell script "/bin/rm " & quoted form of coatedToDelete & space & quoted form of uncoatedToDelete with administrator privileges

  --Successful deletion notification
  display dialog ("The outdated color book deletion was successful!") buttons {"Great!"} with icon note


on error
  --Error message notification
  display dialog ("This script was unable to delete your legacy Pantone color books.") buttons {"OK"} with icon caution
end try
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. So there is definitely no way of doing this outside of a shell script and within Applescript? Also - do you know how to call a shell script from applescript if the script/support files are distributed and you don't know the location to CD in advance.

Comment: There is indeed no way. What is CD?

Comment: I ended up using a bash script like you suggested. Sorry CD was in reference to change directory. Navigating to the parent folder of the script regardless of where it's located has been somewhat of a pain point for me in bash as well as applescript.